# proof of maximum-minimum theorem using gauges.

Tags: real-analysis

in the picture below is the proof of maximum-minimum theorem using gauges from the book of Sherbert and Bartle. I don't understand how $f(x)< \frac{1}{2}(M + f(t))$ when $|x-t| \le \delta (t)$

[image: the picture of the proof in the book]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $t$. By the definition of continuity, for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta$ such that if $|x - t| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(t)| < \epsilon$.

If we take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2} (M - f(t)) > 0$, the above inequality becomes $|f(x) - f(t)| < \frac{1}{2} (M-f(t))$ which implies $f(x) < \frac{1}{2} (M + f(t))$.

Comment: Thanks, now it has started making sense. just one more thing why we let go of the absolute value of f(x) ?

Comment: @kitit The inequality with the absolute value can be rewritten as 2 inequalities via $-\frac{1}{2}(M-f(t)) < f(x) - f(t) < \frac{1}{2} (M - f(t))$. For the proof I guess you only need one of them.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it now.